# Fade other lines when hovering legend in Chart.js

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2

How can I make other lines semi-transparent when I hover "Apples" in the Legend?

Answer (score 1):

For Chart.JS 2.x:

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/rn7ube7v/4/

We need to switch between 2 `dataset.borderColor`s where 1 color has an alpha of `0.2` (20% visible) and `1` (100% visible).

Eg: Using HSL colors to cycle the rainbow for each dataset, we store both the regular color as `dataset.accentColor` and `dataset.accentFadedColor` for when it's not focused.

```js
function steppedHslColor(ratio, alpha) {
  return "hsla(" + 360 * ratio + ', 60%, 55%, ' + alpha + ')';
}
function colorizeDatasets(datasets) {
  for (var i = 0; i < datasets.length; i++) {
    var dataset = datasets[i]
    
    dataset.accentColor = steppedHslColor(i / datasets.length, 1)
    dataset.accentFadedColor = steppedHslColor(i / datasets.length, 0.2)
    
    dataset.backgroundColor = dataset.accentColor
    dataset.borderColor = dataset.accentColor
  }
  return datasets
}

colorizeDatasets(datasets)
```

Then we hook `options.legend.onHover(mouseEvent, legendItem)` to apply the right color.

```js
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: datasets,
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      onHover: function(e, legendItem) {
        if (myChart.hoveringLegendIndex != legendItem.datasetIndex) {
          myChart.hoveringLegendIndex = legendItem.datasetIndex
          for (var i = 0; i < myChart.data.datasets.length; i++) {
            var dataset = myChart.data.datasets[i]
            if (i == legendItem.datasetIndex) {
              dataset.borderColor = dataset.accentColor
            } else {
              dataset.borderColor = dataset.accentFadedColor
            }
          }
          myChart.update()
        }
      }
    },
  },
});
```

There isn't a `config.legend.onLeave` callback unfortunately, so we need to hook `canvas.onmousemove` and see if it leaves the legend area.

```js
myChart.hoveringLegendIndex = -1
myChart.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  if (myChart.hoveringLegendIndex >= 0) {
    if (e.layerX < myChart.legend.left || myChart.legend.right < e.layerX
      || e.layerY < myChart.legend.top || myChart.legend.bottom < e.layerY
    ) {
      myChart.hoveringLegendIndex = -1
      for (var i = 0; i < myChart.data.datasets.length; i++) {
        var dataset = myChart.data.datasets[i]
        dataset.borderColor = dataset.accentColor
      }
      myChart.update()
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Great answer! I am using this functionality on 'onClick'. The chart updates after first click but then stops updating. Values of dataset.borderColor are updating but the Chart is not updating.

Answer (score 1):

For a simpler solution using chart.js 4:

I decided to just gray out the other lines and make them semi-transparent. I put my initial colors in list and I did the following so I can reset the colors `onLeave`:

```
                plugins: {
                   [...]
                    legend: {
                        onHover: (event, legendItem, legend) => {
                            const chart = legend.chart;
                            chart.config.data.datasets.forEach(d => {
                                if (legendItem.text !== d.label) {
                                    d.backgroundColor = "rgba(200,200,200,0.2)";
                                    d.borderColor = "rgba(200,200,200,0.2)"

                                    }
                                })
                            chart.update()
                        },
                        onLeave: (event, legendItem, legend) => {
                            const chart = legend.chart;
                            chart.config.data.datasets.forEach((d,index) => {
                                d.backgroundColor = this.colors[index];
                                d.borderColor = this.colors[index];
                            })
                            chart.update();
                        }
                    },
                },
```

Comment: You can use `arr.forEach((d, index) => {})` you know. The `forEach` function contains the references to the `index` as well as the array itself in the callback arguments. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#index